# Circulo progressivo CSS + Waypoints

Tags: html, jquery, css3

Fala galera,

Eu tenho um circle progress (css puro) e está tudo funcionando perfeitamente, animações e stop no lugar certo.

O problema é que a animação está acontecendo antes do scroll chegar ao elemento. Estou tentando via Waypoint mas não obtive sucesso. Provavelmente porque não manjo muito de jQuery.

Se vocês puderem me ajudar!

Desde já agradeço.

https://jsfiddle.net/tcdLygwj/

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi vc que que a animação só acontece quando o elemento aparecer na tela é isso?

Comment: Exatamente isso!